# Best way of adding a TextView to the main view of a game?

Tags: android

I am currently developing a simple game for Android where the main action occurs on my class GameView, which is simply an extension of View.

I want to add some text showing the score in the top left corner of my GameView, and would like to know the best way of implementing this?

Thanks in advance

Matt Drewery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that your GameView has a canvas since it's drawing graphics, right? In that case, where you do the rest of your drawing, use

```
//canvas.drawText(String text, float x, float y, Paint paint); this is the actual method
canvas.drawText(score, 5, 5, null); //but yours would look more like this
```

Then you would just have to create the "score" String and have it be updated by the game.

Also, you may want to try addView(View child). It would look like this:

```
GameView.addView(TextView);
```

Answer (score 3):

A little shameless self promotion here but if you peek at [Hexaddicus](http://www.sharpermindstech.com/hexaddicus/) you'll see that we split the screen into a game view and a footer which is plain-old-view stuff. This my not be the "look" you are going for but it is *a* way. If you want a more inline look and feel then obviously you should not go down this route.

Just **do not** try to overlay a Android UI widget with your game view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/control_pane"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</FrameLayout>
<com.sharpermindstech.android.hexaddicus.opengl.views.HexBoardView
    android:id="@+id/gamefield" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/control_pane" />
</RelativeLayout>
```